# Why are the significance levels incorrect when presenting survival analysis results in terms of hazard ratios and exporting to LaTeX using stargazer?

Tags: r, stata, survival-analysis, stargazer

I am reproducing in `R` some survival analysis results published in a journal. The original results were produced in Stata. Here are the original results: [image]. Here is the code I use to reproduce these results in `R`.

```
# load packages
library(dplyr)
library(foreign)
library(stargazer)

# load Svolik's original data 
data = read_stata("leaders, institutions, covariates, updated tvc.dta")

# set a t0 for each row
data = mutate(data,t0 = lag(t,default=0), .by=leadid)

# coup survival object original
survobj_coup = Surv(data[["t0"]], data[["_t"]], data$c_coup)

# coup model original
coups_original <- coxph(survobj_coup~legislature +  lgdp_1+ growth_1 +exportersoffuelsmainlyoil_EL2008+ ethfrac_FIXED+ communist+ mil+ cw+ age, 
      data=data, ties="breslow")

# revolt survival object original 
survobj_revolt = Surv(data[["t0"]], data[["_t"]], data$c_revolt)

# revolt model original 
revolt_original <- coxph(survobj_revolt~legislature +  lgdp_1+ growth_1 +exportersoffuelsmainlyoil_EL2008+ ethfrac_FIXED+ mil+ cw+ age, 
                        data=data, ties="breslow")

# natural survival object original
survobj_natural = Surv(data[["t0"]], data[["_t"]], data$c_natural)

# natural model original
natural_original <- coxph(survobj_natural~legislature +  lgdp_1+ growth_1 +exportersoffuelsmainlyoil_EL2008+ ethfrac_FIXED+ communist+ mil+ cw+ age, 
                        data=data, ties="breslow")

# Define a function to exponentiate coefficients
exp_coef <- function(x) { round(exp(x), 3) }

# Create the table using stargazer
stargazer(natural_original, coups_original, revolt_original, apply.coef = exp_coef)
```

Here is the output. Look at Models 1, 3, and 5 (disregard the others). Notice that while the coefficients are the same, the stars are all wonky. Does anyone know what's going on? Interestingly, when I present the results without exponentiating the coefficients (i.e., when I don't present the results in terms of hazard ratios), the stars are correct. But I need to present the results in terms of hazard ratios. Any advice would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the initial study authors presented the results of the NHST without exponentiating the coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stargazer()` function has an argument called `p.auto` which defaults to
`TRUE`. The documentation states:

> a logical value that indicates whether stargazer should calculate the p-values,
> using the standard normal distribution, if coefficients or standard errors are
> supplied by the user (from arguments coef and se) or modified by a function
> (from arguments apply.coef or apply.se).

That is, if you transform the coefficients the default behaviour is to recalculate
p-values from the transformed coefficients and untransformed standard errors
based on the standard normal distribution. In other words: nonsense.

You’ll need to specify `p.auto = FALSE` to keep using the p-values calculated by `coxph()`.
Here’s a reproducible example:

```r
library(survival)
library(stargazer) |> suppressPackageStartupMessages()

fit <- coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age + factor(ecog.ps), data = ovarian)
fit
#> Call:
#> coxph(formula = Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age + factor(ecog.ps), 
#>     data = ovarian)
#> 
#>                     coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z       p
#> age              0.16150   1.17527  0.04992 3.235 0.00122
#> factor(ecog.ps)2 0.01866   1.01884  0.59908 0.031 0.97515
#> 
#> Likelihood ratio test=14.29  on 2 df, p=0.000787
#> n= 26, number of events= 12
```

stargazer reported p-value indicators don’t match:

```r
stargazer(fit, apply.coef = exp, type = "text")
#> 
#> ================================================
#>                          Dependent variable:    
#>                      ---------------------------
#>                                futime           
#> ------------------------------------------------
#> age                           1.175***          
#>                                (0.050)          
#>                                                 
#> factor(ecog.ps)2               1.019*           
#>                                (0.599)          
#>                                                 
#> ------------------------------------------------
#> Observations                     26             
#> R2                              0.423           
#> Max. Possible R2                0.932           
#> Log Likelihood                 -27.838          
#> Wald Test                10.540*** (df = 2)     
#> LR Test                  14.295*** (df = 2)     
#> Score (Logrank) Test     12.261*** (df = 2)     
#> ================================================
#> Note:                *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

… unless you specifically tell it not to recalculate them:

```r
stargazer(fit, apply.coef = exp, type = "text", p.auto = FALSE)
#> 
#> ================================================
#>                          Dependent variable:    
#>                      ---------------------------
#>                                futime           
#> ------------------------------------------------
#> age                           1.175***          
#>                                (0.050)          
#>                                                 
#> factor(ecog.ps)2                1.019           
#>                                (0.599)          
#>                                                 
#> ------------------------------------------------
#> Observations                     26             
#> R2                              0.423           
#> Max. Possible R2                0.932           
#> Log Likelihood                 -27.838          
#> Wald Test                10.540*** (df = 2)     
#> LR Test                  14.295*** (df = 2)     
#> Score (Logrank) Test     12.261*** (df = 2)     
#> ================================================
#> Note:                *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```